# Deleting InfluxDB points with no tag

Tags: influxdb

I have a few points that I am trying to remove that came from bad data and keep reading that you can't really do it but find it hard to believe you *really* can't.

They have no tags so I tried to give them tags by overwriting them with a tag, then deleting the tag, but it didn't overwrite and i just deleted the new tagged values.

I have the time so tried to delete with `where time = 'x'` but get a 400 from Chronograf, tried again in Influx CLI with `DELETE FROM "apps" where time = '2019-05-01T17:45:00Z'` and it runs with no errors, but doesn't actually delete the point.

I understand that because of the way Influx indexes things you can't delete based on fields, but there has to be a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen explicit examples on deleting series with no tags in official Influxdata docs. But approach like in example below worked for me in test - it drops all series in measurement `demo` with empty tags. Be careful to include all possible measurement tag names in `where` clause or you risk to drop good data too.

```
> drop measurement demo
> select * from demo
> insert demo,tagA=A,tagB=B value=5 123455
> insert demo,tagA=A value=6 123456
> insert demo value=1 123451
> insert demo value=2 123452
> insert demo value=3 123453
> select * from demo
name: demo
time   tagA tagB value
----   ---- ---- -----
123451           1
123452           2
123453           3
123455 A    B    5
123456 A         6
> drop series from demo where tagA='' and tagB=''
> select * from demo
name: demo
time   tagA tagB value
----   ---- ---- -----
123455 A    B    5
123456 A         6
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea but i'm not sure i can use it as i am not looking to delete all data with no tag, but instead only a certain handful of points, which happen to have no tag.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. `DELETE FROM` worked for me in cli too: `precision rfc3339
delete from newdemo where time = '1970-01-01T00:02:03.453Z'` to delete all data for timestamp or `delete from newdemo where time = '1970-01-01T00:02:03.455Z and tagA = ''` to delete only data with not tagA.
Could it be affected by `precision` setting in your case?

Comment: Thanks, will look into the precision issue, my series is minute precision and i supplied 00 as seconds.